# Undefined UserId

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

So I am trying to do a 1v1 chat but the userid is showing up as undefined when I push up the message, and the other-other users id doesn't show.

```js
if (user.emailVerified) {
    userPic = user.photoURL;
    userId = user.id;
    displayName = user.displayName;

    var pm = database.ref('chat/' + userId);


    // Create a new message and add it to the list.  
    pm.push({
        displayName: displayName,
        userId: userId,
        pic: userPic,
        text: myString.toString(),
        timestamp: new Date().getTime(), // unix timestamp in milliseconds
    })
}
```

This is is the code I am using to push the message up

**Edit**

This is the userID I am talking about
[image]

Comment: you say `Undefined UserId` ... but there's only `user.id` or the global `userId` - so where is this  `UserId` that is  `undefined` - certainly not in your code - except of course it would be, but then so is `ljhgwvliueghgl` as that too isn't ever assigned a value

Comment: Are you sure  that user object contains id?

Comment: `console.log(user)` ... what do you see?

Comment: Yes it does contain the userid, is userid = user.id. The when I push the message, the userid appears in the database. Its undefined in the database but when I push the message, the userid appears.

Comment: I updated the post with a photo, that should tell you what i am talking about

Comment: May be you need to  access to  userId  like this user.userId instead user.id

Comment: Can you try using `database.ref().child('chat').child(userId)` instead of `database.ref('chat/' + userId )`?

Comment: The if statement is closed?

Comment: @AndréKool yes it was that! THank you